# Как динамически вывести блок дивов на HTML-страницу

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Необходимо вывести блок дивов. Например, один контейнер с дивами так, чтобы можно было много раз (50) их (контейнеры) вывести на страницу и заполнить их разными данными (элементами или объектами массива). Используя один на всех .css-файл.
Не пойму, как реализовать. Подскажите может, что почитать. Может использовать jquery?

Comment: А куда именно вам надо вывести (после определённого элемента, вместо тега script) или как?

Comment: И так, попробую перефразировать намного более понятно свой вопрос.
У меня есть массив объектов. поля этих объектов необходимо вывеси в html-файл. это я могу сделать. Но чтоб они вывелись красиво (удобочитаемо) надо выводить их в блоки <div>,соотвественно, использовать блочную вёрстку, т.е. внутри одного есть N-ное количество вложенных. 
так вот.если мой массив состоит из 50 объектов.неохота как то в  <body> прописывать 50 дивов. внимание вопрос.Как мне реализовать скрипт, который сделает динамический вывод этих блоков на страницу,чтобы в каждый такой контейнер вывелась информация о 50 объекта

Answer (score 2):

Почитать про `JavaScript` и `CSS` а именно: `DOM`, `DocumentFragment`, свойство `className` (или хотя бы про `document.write();`), про CSS классы...

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос крайне непонятен, в общем случае вам необходимо хранить состояние и данные дивов, во-вторых, иметь темплейты для этих данных, и в третьих логику для отображания и изменения данных, тут определённо нужен какой-нить MVC фреймворк наподобие [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) или [Spine.js](http://spinejs.com/), хотя при желании можно всё самостоятельно реализовать.

Comment: тогда напишу проще.как динамически вывести блоки <div> на страницу.но не один блок  <div></div> а с вложенными,например такую конструкцию
<div id="container">
<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="header-container">
<div id="source-name"></div>
<div id="addBan">Delete</div>
</div>
<div id="repost-container">
<div id="repost-logo"></div>
<div id="repost-info"></div>
</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
<div id="footer-container">
<div id="post-data"></div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: опять же не вижу проблемы, в цикле идём по элементам массива и форматируем данную строку(разметку, что вы описали) с данными массива, вставляя их в DOM или в какой-нить аккумулятор, который потом вставим в DOM целиком, так даже лучше будет

Comment: @Spectre это мы с вами знаем что такое DOM а @Amigo perfecto  по моему Java от JavaScript отличить не может :)

Comment: Было бы честнее сказать "хочу как в Pinme.ru формировать блоки", а не шифроваться на ровном месте.

Comment: Rules,не надо тут умничать и переходить на личности. 
@Spectre